# norm estimates for Schatten class

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-spaces, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $C
_p$ be the Schatten-p-classes on a separable Hilbert spaces, $p\ge 1$.
Let ${\rm Tr}$ be the standard trace.
Let $y\in C_p$ be a self-adjoint operator (or even a  positive operator) and let $x_n \in C_{p'}$, $\frac1p+\frac1{p'}=1$, be a sequence of self-adjoint operators with $\|x_n\|_{p'}=1$ such that ${\rm Tr}(x_n^*y)\to \|y\|_p$.
Let $u_n |x_n|=x_n $ be the polar decomposition.
Do we have
$$\|u_n^* y - |y|\| _p \to 0, ~{
\rm as~}n\to \infty?$$

Comment: Are you assuming that $\|x_n\|_{p'}=1$?

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle Ah, yes. Of course it should be in the unit ball. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you are happy with the case $y\geq 0$, so let's assume that for simplicity (I expect that small modifications should deal with arbitrary self-adjoint $y$). In that case, **and if** $1<p<\infty$, it is true that $\| u_n^* y - y\|_p \to 0$. I am not sure about the extreme cases $p=1,\infty$, where the uniform convexity argument breaks down.

Here is the argument. It should work more generally in the non-commutative $L_p$ space of an arbitrary von Neumann algebra. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $\|y\|_p=1$. In that case, the unique $x \in C_{p'}$ of norm one such that $Tr(x^* y) = 1$ is $y^{\frac{p}{p'}}$. By the uniform convexity of $C_{p'}$, the assumption that $\|x_n\|_{p'} \leq 1$ and $Tr(x_n^* y) \to 1$ implies that $\| x_n - y^{\frac{p}{p'}}\|_{p'} \to 0$.

Now consider the Mazur map $z=u|z| \in C_{p'} \mapsto M_{p',p}(z) := u |z|^{\frac{p'}{p}} \in C_p$. It is known that it is continuous (and even uniformly continuous when restricted to the unit ball, see for example the papers by [Yves Raynaud](https://jot.theta.ro/jot/archive/2002-048-001/2002-048-001-003.pdf) or [Eric Ricard](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.8334.pdf) for the optimal estimates). Therefore, we obtain
$$\| u_n |x_n|^{\frac{p}{p'}} - y \|_p = \| M_{p',p}(x_n) - M_{p',p}(y^{\frac{p}{p'}})\|_p \to 0.$$

$x_n$ being self-adjoint, we have $u_n = P_n^+-P_n^-$ for orthogonal projections $P_n^+$ and $P_n^-$ commuting with $x_n$ and $|x_n|$. Multiplying on both sides by $P_n^-$ the preceding inequality, we get
$$ \| P_n^- |x_n|^{\frac{p}{p'}} + P_n^- y P_n^-\|_p \to 0.$$
But since $0 \leq P_n^- |x_n|^{\frac{p}{p'}} \leq P_n^- |x_n|^{\frac{p}{p'}} + P_n^- y P_n^-$ ($y$ is positive), we get
$$\||x_n|^{\frac{p}{p'}}- u_n |x_n|^{\frac{p}{p'}}\|_p =2\|P_n^- |x_n|^{\frac{p}{p'}} \|_p \leq  2\| P_n^- |x_n| + P_n^- y P_n^-\|_p \to 0.$$

This allows to conclude:
$$ \|u_n^* y - y\|_p \leq \|u_n^*(y - u_n |x_n|^{\frac{p}{p'}})\|_p + \| |x_n|^{\frac{p}{p'}} - u_n |x_n|^{\frac{p}{p'}}\|_p + \| u_n |x_n|^{\frac{p}{p'}}-y\|_p$$
goes to zero because each term does.

Comment: Beautiful proof. Many thx, Mikael. For the case when $p=1$, Pfitzner has a very similar result, https://www.jstor.org/stable/24715530. Lemma 3.2